# How to edit /etc/apt/sources.list using putty in a VPS setup

Tags: 11.10, ssh, putty

I'm having trouble doing this. How do I edit it? Basically, the VPS is using 11.04 which is, end of life and I'm trying to upgrade to the latest long term release, but I am following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Oneiric

How would I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, pretty simple, eh?
Open putty and establish your connection to the VPS. 
You gotta use a text editor such as *nano* to edit *sources.list*. Run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then navigate to the end the file (a new line maybe) and keep Putty window open of course.

Simply copy the repository addresses you want to add to *sources.list* file to your clipboard.

Then right-click inside the Putty window and repository addresses will be added to the end of the file (if that didn't happen you can write the addresses by hand).

Press `CTRL+O` and then `Enter` to save the file.

That should be it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It gave me this error message: -bash: nano: command not found

Comment: Try `vim`, `emacs` or install another text editor.